# Get rotation of a 3D triangle

Tags: c#, math, 3d

I have three Vector3 points in 3D space. I need to copy the rotation (the tangent?) of this triangle to the orientation of a 3D model. How can I calculate the triangles Vector3 tangent or create a rotation matrix out of those points?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Finding the angle of a triangle is described here: [Find the normal angle of the face of a triangle in 3D, given the co-ordinates of its vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516296/find-the-normal-angle-of-the-face-of-a-triangle-in-3d-given-the-co-ordinated-of)

Suppose you find the normal and call it N'. It should be trivial for you to write the normal of the "unrotated" triangle, N, eg <1, 0, 0>. It should also be trivial to figure out how to rotate from N to N' and you can create a rotation matrix for it with [Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.createfromaxisangle.aspx) in XNA. This matrix should rotate everything like you want.